# Is there a way to tell if a Jupyter notebook is frozen without killing the kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter, freeze

I am working with a very large set of data and certain functions take a long time to run on my machine.  Is there a way to see if the function is still running or if the kernel is frozen without killing the cell?

The example below is being used to compare company names in two different dictionaries of distinct names as keys with a list of words in the name as values.   I have 650000 entries in one dictionary and 100000 in the other.

Example:

```
    def insert(df, entries):
       try:
          df.loc[max(df.index) + 1] = entries
    except ValueError:
          df.loc[0] = entries

    def check_for_matching_phrases(dict1, dict2):
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['filings_name', 'no_match_name', 'percent_match'])
        for key1, value1 in dict1.items():
            for key2, value2 in dict2.items():
                matches = 0
                for val_1 in value1:
                    if val_1 in value2:
                       matches += 1
                denominator = len(min(value1, value2))
                perc_match = matches / denominator
                insert(df, [key1, key2, perc_match])
        return df
```

Comment: Slightly unrelated to your question but you shouldn't really be generating DataFrames the way you are. Pandas is designed to generate DataFrames from a fully populated data structure. Using plain built-in Python data structures and optimizing your loop will likely speed up your workflow significantly. In fact, there's no need to use Pandas at all for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm just using it to easily check different sections of data so I can make sure the data is correct, see which characters are causing the most issues etc.

Comment: You could add a progress bar or have your code print some sort of output

Answer (score 1):

You can easily see if the kernel is still active within the Jupyter notebook. Look at the top right of your browser window and see the little circle next to your kernel name? If it is solid black it is busy (screencap below) and if idle it will be a blank white circle. Hovering over the circle will also explicitly tell you the state. It's not as nice as a progress bar but it does give you some indication.

[example of busy kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH6dO.png)

Answer (score 0):

[tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) is godsend for things like this. If I'm working with a lot of data/processing (whether in a jupyter notebook or in a normal python script) I'll use it to estimate how long my process will take and monitor if it gets stuck at anypoint. You can just pop on the `tqdm` function onto your iterable and viola:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

...

for key1, value1 in tqdm(dict1.items()):
    for key2, value2 in dict2.items():
```

It also works nicely for nested for loops as well:

```
for i in tqdm(range(10), position=0):
    for i in tqdm(range(10000000), position=1, leave=False):
        pass
```